# To provide title attribute for an background image inside div tag

Tags: html, css

Is there a solution for adding a title attribute to the image that is displayed as a background image for div tag. The current code is like

```
<div style="background:transparent url(image/smiley.jpg) left bottom; cursor:pointer;">
```

I would like to add a title attribute "Smiley" to the background image smiley.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a `title` attribute on the `div`. Since the `background-image` repeats by default, it will fill the `div`.

```
<div title="Smiley" style="background:transparent url(image/smiley.jpg) left bottom; cursor:pointer;">
```

But assume for a moment that the image was set to `no-repeat` and was smaller than the `div` itself. In that case, you could not (without JavaScript) display a tooltip only when the cursor is over the `background-image`.

Comment: The important point here is that attributes can only be on elements, of which style declarations are not a part.

Comment: Thanks but can I add a alt attribute too like this @Kevin

Comment: @MasterWingChun Don't know if that works, but it would not be valid code. The `alt` attribute is specified for image related tags like `img` and `area`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding your alt text inside the div, then setting the text-indent to a negative value like -9999px.  In this way, Google can read the copy, but the text is moved off the page when viewed in a browser.

Comment: This is a variation of [Fahrner Image Replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrner_Image_Replacement), and each version has a down side.